# How can I verify a class method signature?

Tags: c++, class, templates, types

I can verify a function signature as follows:

```cpp
template <typename>
struct FnType
{
  static bool const valid = false;
};

struct FnType<void(int)>
{
  static bool const valid = true;
};

void foo(int)
{

}

FnType<decltype(foo)>::valid; //true
```

How can I verify a class method signature?

```cpp
class Y
{
public:
  void foo(int)
  {

  }
};

FnType<decltype(&Y::foo)>::valid; //false??
```

I want to verify `Y::foo` return type and argument types are valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add another partial specialization for member function pointers. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct FnType<void(T::*)(int)>
{
  static bool const valid = true;
};
```

then

```
FnType<decltype(&Y::foo)>::valid; //true
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eguAbYfM5svdrsIC)